# Vue validation without form

Tags: vue.js, validation

I'm trying to validate input fields inside children components but using steps (each component it's a step), the action buttons (back and next) it's in parent component, i'm confused (logically) how's the best way to do that, i don't know if i use a library or the best way is validate inside each component

The active component is based in v-show="step" in each children component
I'm using a watch for step to control all actions in the children components and trigger children functions using $refs if is necessary.
**Form.vue**

```
        <StepGuide class="mb-5" :step="step"></StepGuide>
        <StepOne ref="step1" v-show="step == 1"></StepOne>
        <StepTwo ref="step2" v-show="step == 2"></StepTwo>
        <StepThree ref="step3" v-show="step == 3"></StepThree>
        <StepFour ref="step4" v-show="step == 4"></StepFour>
        <StepFive ref="step5" v-show="step == 5"></StepFive>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-3 text-center mt-4 d-flex justify-content-around">
                <button type="button" @click="step--" key="back" v-if="step > 1" class="px-4 py-2 rounded btn-add">Anterior</button>
                <button type="button" @click="step++" key="next" v-if="step < 5" class="px-4 py-2 rounded btn-add">Próximo</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**StepOne Component Input Example**

```
     <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label for="customer">Nome do cliente *</label>
        <input
            name="customer_name"
            class="form-control"
            id="customerName" 
            type="text"
            v-model="customer.name"
            
        />
    </div>
```

Comment: @MatheusCelini it's not enough, we need your full code including JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the Vuetify source code (it's a UI library) - you will see how they use the `provide + inject` pattern where the form (a parent component) provides a function which is injected by each form field component which is capable of validating its own content. The form fields call the provided (and injected) function with a boolean argument TRUE to notify the form about their existence (because they might not be a direct parent of the form) and with FALSE to unsubscribe from the form (in `beforeUnmount` hook).
The form (through this notification function) collects a list of the form field components and when the form must be validated - it calls the `validate()` method of each subscribed form field. The form fields on the other hand take care of the validation of their own content - and show appropriate error messages. The form fields are also expected to provide a method `reset` to clear the validation errors.

You can start with the following example and extend it for your own use case.

```html
<template>
  <form v-bind="$attrs" v-on="listeners">
    <slot />
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  name: 'FormValidator',
  provide()
  {
    return {
      form: this
    };
  },
  inheritAttrs: false,
  data()
  {
    return {
      fieldList: [],
    };
  },
  computed:
    {
      listeners()
      {
        return {
          ...this.$listeners,
          submit: (evt) =>
          {
            evt.preventDefault();
            this.fieldList.forEach(item =>
            {
              item.setDirty(true);
            });
            this.$nextTick(() =>
            {
              this.$emit('submit', evt);
            });
          }
        };
      }
    },
  methods:
    {
      register(field)
      {
        this.fieldList.push(field);
      },
      unregister(field)
      {
        const idx = this.fieldList.indexOf(field);
        if (idx !== -1) this.fieldList.splice(idx, 1);
      },
      valid()
      {
        const fields = this.fieldList;
        return fields.every(item => item.valid);
      },
      reset()
      {
        this.fieldList.forEach(item => item.setDirty(false));
      },
    }
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="form_field">
    <label v-if="label" style="text-align: initial;">{{ label }}</label>
    <div class="form_group" @input="setDirty" @change="setDirty">
      <div v-if="$slots.prepend" class="form_input_prepend">
        <slot name="prepend" />
      </div>
      <slot />
      <div v-if="$slots.append" class="form_input_append">
        <slot name="append" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-if="error && (dirty || force)" class="field_error">{{ error }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  name: 'FormField',
  inject:
    {
      form:
        {
          default: null
        }
    },
  props:
    {
      label:
        {
          type: String,
          default: ''
        },
      error:
        {
          // the actual validation happens in your own code - you just provide an error message here (if any)
          type: String,
          default: null
        },
      force:
        {
          // force real-time validation, no matter if the value is dirty or not
          type: Boolean,
          default: false
        },
    },
  data()
  {
    return {
      dirty: false,
    };
  },
  computed:
    {
      valid() // eslint-disable-line vue/no-unused-properties
      {
        return !this.error;
      }
    },
  created()
  {
    this.form && this.form.register(this);
  },
  beforeDestroy()
  {
    this.form && this.form.unregister(this);
  },
  methods:
    {
      setDirty(value)
      {
        this.dirty = value;
      }
    }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  $field_radius: 4px;
  $input_disabled: grey;

  .form_field
  {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .form_field + .form_field
  {
    margin-top: 8px;
  }

  .form_field > label
  {
    padding-bottom: 4px;
  }

  .form_group
  {
    border: 1px solid $dialog_border;
    border-radius: $field_radius;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: $input_prepend;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  .form_group:focus-within
  {
    border-color: blue;
  }

  .form_group input,
  .form_group select,
  .form_group textarea
  {
    border: none;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 0 6px;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: calc(1.5rem + 8px);
    min-width: 48px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: $field_radius; /* probably should be conditional - based on the absence of prepend/append slot contents */
  }

  .form_group select
  {
    background: white;
  }

  .form_group textarea
  {
    height: auto;
  }

  .form_group input[type="file"]
  {
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 0;
  }

  .form_group input:focus,
  .form_group select:focus,
  .form_group textarea:focus
  {
    outline: none;
  }

  .form_group input:disabled,
  .form_group select:disabled,
  .form_group textarea:disabled
  {
    background-color: $input_disabled;
  }

  .form_group > *:not(.form_input_prepend):not(.form_input_append)
  {
    align-self: stretch;
  }

  .form_input_prepend,
  .form_input_append
  {
    /* background-color: $input_prepend; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .form_input_prepend
  {
    border-top-left-radius: $field_radius;
    border-bottom-left-radius: $field_radius;
  }

  .form_input_append
  {
    border-top-right-radius: $field_radius;
    border-bottom-right-radius: $field_radius;
  }

  .field_error
  {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 85%;
    color: red;
    margin: 3px 0;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? Here is a well supported library **Vee-Validate** with more then 500k downloads to help you get a form with all it's life cycles and states.
We used in our current project and it shows only success [Vee-Validate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vee-validate)

you can check a live examples also [here](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/examples/checkboxes-and-radio/)